# Show documents from Array with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to "create" new documents, to keep only the contents of the activities.
I've looked at `$project` and `$unwide`, but I didn't find any appropriate result.

Here is my MongoDB query:

```js
  const activities = await friendModel.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        $or: [
          {
            ReceiverId: ActorId,
            Status: 1,
          },
          {
            RequesterId: ActorId,
            Status: 1,
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      $set: {
        fieldResult: {
          $cond: {
            if: {
              $eq: [ "$ReceiverId", ActorId ],
            },
            then: "$RequesterId",
            else: "$ReceiverId",
          },
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "activities",
        localField: "fieldResult",
        foreignField: "ActorId",
        as: "activity",
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: "$activity",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
      }
    },
    { $sort: { "activity._Date": -1 } },
    { $skip: request.pageindex * 3 },
    { $limit: 3 },
  ]);
```

Here is what I would like to do: https://sourceb.in/7u0tirIstt
Here is what I get for the moment: https://sourceb.in/Ped2xY5Ml8

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to add `$project` as follows:

```
...
 {
  $project: {
      "_id":"$_id",
      "ActivityId": "$activity._id",
      "ActorId": "$activity.ActorId",
      "Type": "$activity.Type",
      "_Date": "$activity._Date",
      "MovieId": "$activity.MovieId",
      "FriendId": "$activity.FriendId",
      "ContestId": "$activity.ContestId",
      "LookId": "$activity.LookId",
      "__v": "$__v"
  },
},
...
```

You can access values with `$`, and map nested values by accessing them directly

Also would recommend you doing a limit before you do lookup to speed it up a bit

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @noitse! If a friend has no activity, I have to delete the document. Because at this moment, "activity" is not created, which causes me an unwanted result at the end: `{"_id":"627d77a9990fff996621d505","__v":0}`.

But I don't know how to do it. Do you have an idea please?

Comment: Total result:
`[{"_id":"62a65626883ce6b43da9ec98","ActivityId":"62b1d1d5ce3a7f96e92aa6c9","ActorId":108,"Type":3,"_Date":"2022-06-21T14:12:37.868Z","MovieId":0,"FriendId":0,"ContestId":0,"LookId":0,"__v":0},{"_id":"627d7828990fff996621d5ea","ActivityId":"62af651cbc48f1e1b94c1935","ActorId":3,"Type":3,"_Date":"2022-06-19T18:04:12.016Z","MovieId":0,"FriendId":0,"ContestId":0,"LookId":0,"__v":0},{"_id":"627d77a9990fff996621d505","__v":0}]`

Comment: @cypolo Yup, you could do another match after your lookup and unwind
`{ $match: { activity: { $exists: true } } },`